# Rails migration error database_authenticatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

-- create_table(:admin_users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `database_authenticatable' for #

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
How to solv it? Thanx!

migration

```
create_table(:admin_users) do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable
      t.timestamps
end
```

have all gems in gemfile and installed

Comment: What does the migration look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is simple device team sucks!!!
to solve this need make cnanges in GEMFILE
gem 'devise', "~> 1.5"

because in 1.5 there is database_authenticatable type support and in 2.1.0 there is support of only compatibility not creation of fields with this type
thanx everybody.

Comment: Is it really that much harder to add in the columns without the helper methods? I personally like it better since, with the new schema, I can see exactly what devise is adding to my db and understand it a little bit more. But, everyone has their own opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have devise in the Gemfile and the bundle is installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just getting started with devise (vs updating from previous verions), you might have missed the following step before doing `rake db:migrate`

```
rails generate devise:install
```

This creates

```
create  config/initializers/devise.rb
create  config/locales/devise.en.yml
```

which define the method rake is complaining about above.

Source:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 0):

With Devise 2.0 and newer, the migration helper methods (t.database_authenticatable for example) are not available (as stated on the wiki [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-change-an-already-existing-table-to-add-devise-required-columns) ) If you're making a new model for users, just use the devise migration generator like so:

```
rails g devise admin_users (If you're installing devise on your app)
```

If you're adding the required fields to an existing user model, you should check [this page on the devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style).

Check out the [main README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for devise, which has up-to-date information for installing the latest version of devise on Rails.